# Read data in Oracle data reader parallelly in .Net

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, parallel-processing

I am processing data from an Oracle Data Reader in C#, that has about 10000 rows of data on average. Is there a way to do the processing parallelly so each CPU can have it's turn at reading the next row from the same Data Reader and writing it to the same spreadsheet? 
In a sequential execution, this process is taking about 10-15 minutes and here is my sequential code.

```
OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(select_query, connection);
OracleDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
while (reader.Read()){
    for(int i = 1; i <= reader.FieldCount; i++){
        worksheet[counter, i] = reader.GetValue(i).ToString();
    }
    counter++;
}
```

The end result is to have all the rows written to a spreadsheet. 
Can someone please help me out as I am new to parallel programming? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are not going to get faster IO by slitting it on separate CPUs.  You do know you  can connect to a database in Excel and import data?

Comment: @Blam, There is a lot more data processing going on before it is written to Excel. Plus this is only a small portion of a big project!

Comment: Not sure about write speed but I know I have read fast using this adapter.  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316934

Answer (score 0):

Your problem isn't the data reader. I commonly pull tens or hundreds of thousands of records from Oracle  through data reader in seconds (and do for a couple of commercial tools).

Either the link to the database is limiting your transfer speed, or your spreadsheet API is dominating the whole operation.

My recommendation is to decouple the reader loop from the spreadsheet build.

1. Read all 10,000 rows into a list / array of values
2. Iterate the array of values, build the spreadsheet

This suggestion is so you can Track the time separately. I honestly think the spreadsheet API you are using may be the bottleneck because I typically don't have this sort of performance with exporting Oracle to Excel. Perhaps try a different spreadsheet library.

Comment: I am using the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel API to create the spreadsheet. Can you please let me know if there is a better API (commercial or free) that works better? Thanks